# PHP Strict Standards: Declaration of ezSQL_mysql::escape() should be compatible with ezSQLcore::escape() in /home

Tags: mysql, ezsql

i have problem about ezSQL_mysql and ezSQLcore, it may be an incompatible version of PHP, I share the code below. what version of Php should I use or what should I do to tailor mysqli? (my php version 5.6 )
codes :

**ezSQL_mysql**

```
<?php

/**********************************************************************
*  Author: Justin Vincent (jv@jvmultimedia.com)
*  Web...: http://twitter.com/justinvincent
*  Name..: ezSQL_mysql
*  Desc..: mySQL component (part of ezSQL databse abstraction library)
*
*/

/**********************************************************************
*  ezSQL error strings - mySQL
*/

$ezsql_mysql_str = array
(
    1 => 'Require $dbuser and $dbpassword to connect to a database server',
    2 => 'Error establishing mySQL database connection. Correct user/password? Correct hostname? Database server running?',
    3 => 'Require $dbname to select a database',
    4 => 'mySQL database connection is not active',
    5 => 'Unexpected error while trying to select database'
);

/**********************************************************************
*  ezSQL Database specific class - mySQL
*/

if ( ! function_exists ('mysql_connect') ) die('<b>Fatal Error:</b> ezSQL_mysql requires mySQL Lib to be compiled and or linked in to the PHP engine');
if ( ! class_exists ('ezSQLcore') ) die('<b>Fatal Error:</b> ezSQL_mysql requires ezSQLcore (ez_sql_core.php) to be included/loaded before it can be used');

class ezSQL_mysql extends ezSQLcore
{

    var $dbuser = false;
    var $dbpassword = false;
    var $dbname = false;
    var $dbhost = false;

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Constructor - allow the user to perform a qucik connect at the
    *  same time as initialising the ezSQL_mysql class
    */

    function ezSQL_mysql($dbuser='**', $dbpassword='**', $dbname='**', $dbhost='localhost')
    {
        $this->dbuser = $dbuser;
        $this->dbpassword = $dbpassword;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
        $this->dbhost = $dbhost;
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Short hand way to connect to mySQL database server
    *  and select a mySQL database at the same time
    */

    function quick_connect($dbuser='**', $dbpassword='**', $dbname='**', $dbhost='localhost')
    {
        $return_val = false;
        if ( ! $this->connect($dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbhost,true) ) ;
        else if ( ! $this->select($dbname) ) ;
        else $return_val = true;
        return $return_val;
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Try to connect to mySQL database server
    */

    function connect($dbuser='**', $dbpassword='**', $dbhost='localhost')
    {
        global $ezsql_mysql_str; $return_val = false;

        // Must have a user and a password
        if ( ! $dbuser )
        {
            $this->register_error($ezsql_mysql_str[1].' in '.__FILE__.' on line '.__LINE__);
            $this->show_errors ? trigger_error($ezsql_mysql_str[1],E_USER_WARNING) : null;
        }
        // Try to establish the server database handle
        else if ( ! $this->dbh = @mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword,true) )
        {
            $this->register_error($ezsql_mysql_str[2].' in '.__FILE__.' on line '.__LINE__);
            $this->show_errors ? trigger_error($ezsql_mysql_str[2],E_USER_WARNING) : null;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->dbuser = $dbuser;
            $this->dbpassword = $dbpassword;
            $this->dbhost = $dbhost;
            $return_val = true;
        }

        return $return_val;
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Try to select a mySQL database
    */

    function select($dbname='**')
    {
        global $ezsql_mysql_str; $return_val = false;

        // Must have a database name
        if ( ! $dbname )
        {
            $this->register_error($ezsql_mysql_str[3].' in '.__FILE__.' on line '.__LINE__);
            $this->show_errors ? trigger_error($ezsql_mysql_str[3],E_USER_WARNING) : null;
        }

        // Must have an active database connection
        else if ( ! $this->dbh )
        {
            $this->register_error($ezsql_mysql_str[4].' in '.__FILE__.' on line '.__LINE__);
            $this->show_errors ? trigger_error($ezsql_mysql_str[4],E_USER_WARNING) : null;
        }

        // Try to connect to the database
        else if ( !@mysql_select_db($dbname,$this->dbh) )
        {
            // Try to get error supplied by mysql if not use our own
            if ( !$str = @mysql_error($this->dbh))
                  $str = $ezsql_mysql_str[5];

            $this->register_error($str.' in '.__FILE__.' on line '.__LINE__);
            $this->show_errors ? trigger_error($str,E_USER_WARNING) : null;
        }
        else
        {
            include 'sql_for_tr.php';
            $this->dbname = $dbname;
            $return_val = true;
        }

        return $return_val;
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Format a mySQL string correctly for safe mySQL insert
    *  (no mater if magic quotes are on or not)
    */

    function escape($str)
    {
        return mysql_escape_string(stripslashes($str));
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Return mySQL specific system date syntax
    *  i.e. Oracle: SYSDATE Mysql: NOW()
    */

    function sysdate()
    {
        return 'NOW()';
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Perform mySQL query and try to detirmin result value
    */

    function query($query)
    {

        // Initialise return
        $return_val = 0;

        // Flush cached values..
        $this->flush();

        // For reg expressions
        $query = trim($query);

        // Log how the function was called
        $this->func_call = "\$db->query(\"$query\")";

        // Keep track of the last query for debug..
        $this->last_query = $query;

        // Count how many queries there have been
        $this->num_queries++;

        // Use core file cache function
        if ( $cache = $this->get_cache($query) )
        {
            return $cache;
        }

        // If there is no existing database connection then try to connect
        if ( ! isset($this->dbh) || ! $this->dbh )
        {
            $this->connect($this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $this->dbhost);
            $this->select($this->dbname);
        }

        // Perform the query via std mysql_query function..
        $this->result = @mysql_query($query,$this->dbh);

        // If there is an error then take note of it..
        if ( $str = @mysql_error($this->dbh) )
        {
            $is_insert = true;
            $this->register_error($str);
            $this->show_errors ? trigger_error($str,E_USER_WARNING) : null;
            return true;
        }

        // Query was an insert, delete, update, replace
        $is_insert = false;
        if ( preg_match("/^(insert|delete|update|replace)\s+/i",$query) )
        {
            $this->rows_affected = @mysql_affected_rows();

            // Take note of the insert_id
            if ( preg_match("/^(insert|replace)\s+/i",$query) )
            {
                $this->insert_id = @mysql_insert_id($this->dbh);
            }

            // Return number fo rows affected
            $return_val = $this->rows_affected;
        }
        // Query was a select
        else
        {

            // Take note of column info
            $i=0;
            while ($i < @mysql_num_fields($this->result))
            {
                $this->col_info[$i] = @mysql_fetch_field($this->result);
                $i++;
            }

            // Store Query Results
            $num_rows=0;
            while ( $row = @mysql_fetch_object($this->result) )
            {
                // Store relults as an objects within main array
                $this->last_result[$num_rows] = $row;
                $num_rows++;
            }

            @mysql_free_result($this->result);

            // Log number of rows the query returned
            $this->num_rows = $num_rows;

            // Return number of rows selected
            $return_val = $this->num_rows;
        }

        // disk caching of queries
        $this->store_cache($query,$is_insert);

        // If debug ALL queries
        $this->trace || $this->debug_all ? $this->debug() : null ;

        return $return_val;

    }

}
```

?>

**ezSQLcore**

```
<?php

/**********************************************************************
*  Author: Justin Vincent (jv@jvmultimedia.com)
*  Web...: http://twitter.com/justinvincent
*  Name..: ezSQL
*  Desc..: ezSQL Core module - database abstraction library to make
*          it very easy to deal with databases.
*
*/

/**********************************************************************
*  ezSQL Constants
*/

define('EZSQL_VERSION','2.03');
define('OBJECT','OBJECT',true);
define('ARRAY_A','ARRAY_A',true);
define('ARRAY_N','ARRAY_N',true);
define('EZSQL_CORE_ERROR','ezSQLcore can not be used by itself (it is designed for use by database specific modules).');


/**********************************************************************
*  Core class containg common functions to manipulate query result
*  sets once returned
*/

class ezSQLcore
{

    var $trace            = false;  // same as $debug_all
    var $debug_all        = false;  // same as $trace
    var $debug_called     = false;
    var $vardump_called   = false;
    var $show_errors      = true;
    var $num_queries      = 0;
    var $last_query       = null;
    var $last_error       = null;
    var $col_info         = null;
    var $captured_errors  = array();
    var $cache_dir        = false;
    var $cache_queries    = false;
    var $cache_inserts    = false;
    var $use_disk_cache   = false;
    var $cache_timeout    = 24; // hours

    // == TJH == default now needed for echo of debug function
    var $debug_echo_is_on = true;

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Constructor
    */

    function ezSQLcore()
    {
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Connect to DB - over-ridden by specific DB class
    */

    function connect()
    {
        die(EZSQL_CORE_ERROR);
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Select DB - over-ridden by specific DB class
    */

    function select()
    {
        die(EZSQL_CORE_ERROR);
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Basic Query  - over-ridden by specific DB class
    */

    function query()
    {
        die(EZSQL_CORE_ERROR);
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Format a string correctly for safe insert - over-ridden by specific
    *  DB class
    */

    function escape()
    {
        die(EZSQL_CORE_ERROR);
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Return database specific system date syntax
    *  i.e. Oracle: SYSDATE Mysql: NOW()
    */

    function sysdate()
    {
        die(EZSQL_CORE_ERROR);
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Print SQL/DB error - over-ridden by specific DB class
    */

    function register_error($err_str)
    {
        // Keep track of last error
        $this->last_error = $err_str;

        // Capture all errors to an error array no matter what happens
        $this->captured_errors[] = array
        (
            'error_str' => $err_str,
            'query'     => $this->last_query
        );
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Turn error handling on or off..
    */

    function show_errors()
    {
        $this->show_errors = true;
    }

    function hide_errors()
    {
        $this->show_errors = false;
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Kill cached query results
    */

    function flush()
    {
        // Get rid of these
        $this->last_result = null;
        $this->col_info = null;
        $this->last_query = null;
        $this->from_disk_cache = false;
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Get one variable from the DB - see docs for more detail
    */

    function get_var($query=null,$x=0,$y=0)
    {

        // Log how the function was called
        $this->func_call = "\$db->get_var(\"$query\",$x,$y)";

        // If there is a query then perform it if not then use cached results..
        if ( $query )
        {
            $this->query($query);
        }

        // Extract var out of cached results based x,y vals
        if ( $this->last_result[$y] )
        {
            $values = array_values(get_object_vars($this->last_result[$y]));
        }

        // If there is a value return it else return null
        return (isset($values[$x]) && $values[$x]!=='')?$values[$x]:null;
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Get one row from the DB - see docs for more detail
    */

    function get_row($query=null,$output=OBJECT,$y=0)
    {

        // Log how the function was called
        $this->func_call = "\$db->get_row(\"$query\",$output,$y)";

        // If there is a query then perform it if not then use cached results..
        if ( $query )
        {
            $this->query($query);
        }

        // If the output is an object then return object using the row offset..
        if ( $output == OBJECT )
        {
            return $this->last_result[$y]?$this->last_result[$y]:null;
        }
        // If the output is an associative array then return row as such..
        elseif ( $output == ARRAY_A )
        {
            return $this->last_result[$y]?get_object_vars($this->last_result[$y]):null;
        }
        // If the output is an numerical array then return row as such..
        elseif ( $output == ARRAY_N )
        {
            return $this->last_result[$y]?array_values(get_object_vars($this->last_result[$y])):null;
        }
        // If invalid output type was specified..
        else
        {
            $this->print_error(" \$db->get_row(string query, output type, int offset) -- Output type must be one of: OBJECT, ARRAY_A, ARRAY_N");
        }

    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Function to get 1 column from the cached result set based in X index
    *  see docs for usage and info
    */

    function get_col($query=null,$x=0)
    {

        // If there is a query then perform it if not then use cached results..
        if ( $query )
        {
            $this->query($query);
        }

        // Extract the column values
        for ( $i=0; $i < count($this->last_result); $i++ )
        {
            $new_array[$i] = $this->get_var(null,$x,$i);
        }

        return $new_array;
    }


    /**********************************************************************
    *  Return the the query as a result set - see docs for more details
    */

    function get_results($query=null, $output = OBJECT)
    {

        // Log how the function was called
        $this->func_call = "\$db->get_results(\"$query\", $output)";

        // If there is a query then perform it if not then use cached results..
        if ( $query )
        {
            $this->query($query);
        }

        // Send back array of objects. Each row is an object
        if ( $output == OBJECT )
        {
            return $this->last_result;
        }
        elseif ( $output == ARRAY_A || $output == ARRAY_N )
        {
            if ( $this->last_result )
            {
                $i=0;
                foreach( $this->last_result as $row )
                {

                    $new_array[$i] = get_object_vars($row);

                    if ( $output == ARRAY_N )
                    {
                        $new_array[$i] = array_values($new_array[$i]);
                    }

                    $i++;
                }

                return $new_array;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }


    /**********************************************************************
    *  Function to get column meta data info pertaining to the last query
    * see docs for more info and usage
    */

    function get_col_info($info_type="name",$col_offset=-1)
    {

        if ( $this->col_info )
        {
            if ( $col_offset == -1 )
            {
                $i=0;
                foreach($this->col_info as $col )
                {
                    $new_array[$i] = $col->{$info_type};
                    $i++;
                }
                return $new_array;
            }
            else
            {
                return $this->col_info[$col_offset]->{$info_type};
            }

        }

    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  store_cache
    */

    function store_cache($query,$is_insert)
    {

        // The would be cache file for this query
        $cache_file = $this->cache_dir.'/'.md5($query);

        // disk caching of queries
        if ( $this->use_disk_cache && ( $this->cache_queries && ! $is_insert ) || ( $this->cache_inserts && $is_insert ))
        {
            if ( ! is_dir($this->cache_dir) )
            {
                $this->register_error("Could not open cache dir: $this->cache_dir");
                $this->show_errors ? trigger_error("Could not open cache dir: $this->cache_dir",E_USER_WARNING) : null;
            }
            else
            {
                // Cache all result values
                $result_cache = array
                (
                    'col_info' => $this->col_info,
                    'last_result' => $this->last_result,
                    'num_rows' => $this->num_rows,
                    'return_value' => $this->num_rows,
                );
                error_log ( serialize($result_cache), 3, $cache_file);
            }
        }

    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  get_cache
    */

    function get_cache($query)
    {

        // The would be cache file for this query
        $cache_file = $this->cache_dir.'/'.md5($query);

        // Try to get previously cached version
        if ( $this->use_disk_cache && file_exists($cache_file) )
        {
            // Only use this cache file if less than 'cache_timeout' (hours)
            if ( (time() - filemtime($cache_file)) > ($this->cache_timeout*3600) )
            {
                unlink($cache_file);
            }
            else
            {
                $result_cache = unserialize(file_get_contents($cache_file));

                $this->col_info = $result_cache['col_info'];
                $this->last_result = $result_cache['last_result'];
                $this->num_rows = $result_cache['num_rows'];

                $this->from_disk_cache = true;

                // If debug ALL queries
                $this->trace || $this->debug_all ? $this->debug() : null ;

                return $result_cache['return_value'];
            }
        }

    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Dumps the contents of any input variable to screen in a nicely
    *  formatted and easy to understand way - any type: Object, Var or Array
    */

    function vardump($mixed='')
    {

        // Start outup buffering
        ob_start();

        echo "<p><table><tr><td bgcolor=ffffff><blockquote><font color=000090>";
        echo "<pre><font face=arial>";

        if ( ! $this->vardump_called )
        {
            echo "<font color=800080><b>ezSQL</b> (v".EZSQL_VERSION.") <b>Variable Dump..</b></font>\n\n";
        }

        $var_type = gettype ($mixed);
        print_r(($mixed?$mixed:"<font color=red>No Value / False</font>"));
        echo "\n\n<b>Type:</b> " . ucfirst($var_type) . "\n";
        echo "<b>Last Query</b> [$this->num_queries]<b>:</b> ".($this->last_query?$this->last_query:"NULL")."\n";
        echo "<b>Last Function Call:</b> " . ($this->func_call?$this->func_call:"None")."\n";
        echo "<b>Last Rows Returned:</b> ".count($this->last_result)."\n";
        echo "</font></pre></font></blockquote></td></tr></table>".$this->donation();
        echo "\n<hr size=1 noshade color=dddddd>";

        // Stop output buffering and capture debug HTML
        $html = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        // Only echo output if it is turned on
        if ( $this->debug_echo_is_on )
        {
            echo $html;
        }

        $this->vardump_called = true;

        return $html;

    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Alias for the above function
    */

    function dumpvar($mixed)
    {
        $this->vardump($mixed);
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Displays the last query string that was sent to the database & a
    * table listing results (if there were any).
    * (abstracted into a seperate file to save server overhead).
    */

    function debug()
    {

        // Start outup buffering
        ob_start();

        echo "<blockquote>";

        // Only show ezSQL credits once..
        if ( ! $this->debug_called )
        {
            echo "<font color=800080 face=arial size=2><b>ezSQL</b> (v".EZSQL_VERSION.") <b>Debug..</b></font><p>\n";
        }

        if ( $this->last_error )
        {
            echo "<font face=arial size=2 color=000099><b>Last Error --</b> [<font color=000000><b>$this->last_error</b></font>]<p>";
        }

        if ( $this->from_disk_cache )
        {
            echo "<font face=arial size=2 color=000099><b>Results retrieved from disk cache</b></font><p>";
        }

        echo "<font face=arial size=2 color=000099><b>Query</b> [$this->num_queries] <b>--</b> ";
        echo "[<font color=000000><b>$this->last_query</b></font>]</font><p>";

            echo "<font face=arial size=2 color=000099><b>Query Result..</b></font>";
            echo "<blockquote>";

        if ( $this->col_info )
        {

            // =====================================================
            // Results top rows

            echo "<table cellpadding=5 cellspacing=1 bgcolor=555555>";
            echo "<tr bgcolor=eeeeee><td nowrap valign=bottom><font color=555599 face=arial size=2><b>(row)</b></font></td>";


            for ( $i=0; $i < count($this->col_info); $i++ )
            {
                echo "<td nowrap align=left valign=top><font size=1 color=555599 face=arial>{$this->col_info[$i]->type} {$this->col_info[$i]->max_length}</font><br><span style='font-family: arial; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold;'>{$this->col_info[$i]->name}</span></td>";
            }

            echo "</tr>";

            // ======================================================
            // print main results

        if ( $this->last_result )
        {

            $i=0;
            foreach ( $this->get_results(null,ARRAY_N) as $one_row )
            {
                $i++;
                echo "<tr bgcolor=ffffff><td bgcolor=eeeeee nowrap align=middle><font size=2 color=555599 face=arial>$i</font></td>";

                foreach ( $one_row as $item )
                {
                    echo "<td nowrap><font face=arial size=2>$item</font></td>";
                }

                echo "</tr>";
            }

        } // if last result
        else
        {
            echo "<tr bgcolor=ffffff><td colspan=".(count($this->col_info)+1)."><font face=arial size=2>No Results</font></td></tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";

        } // if col_info
        else
        {
            echo "<font face=arial size=2>No Results</font>";
        }

        echo "</blockquote></blockquote>".$this->donation()."<hr noshade color=dddddd size=1>";

        // Stop output buffering and capture debug HTML
        $html = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        // Only echo output if it is turned on
        if ( $this->debug_echo_is_on )
        {
            echo $html;
        }

        $this->debug_called = true;

        return $html;

    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *  Naughty little function to ask for some remuniration!
    */

    function donation()
    {
        return "<font size=1 face=arial color=000000>If ezSQL has helped <a href=\"https://www.paypal.com/xclick/business=justin%40justinvincent.com&item_name=ezSQL&no_note=1&tax=0\" style=\"color: 0000CC;\">make a donation!?</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;<!--[ go on! you know you want to! ]--></font>";
    }

}
```

### ?>

i have problem about ezSQL_mysql and ezSQLcore, it may be an incompatible version of PHP, I share the code below. what version of Php should I use or what should I do to tailor mysqli?
what kind of arrangement should I make? thanks for helping.

Comment: Number 1, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: i using 5.6 native

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your implementation you have:

```
function escape($str)
```

While in core they have:

```
function escape()
```

They need to match exactly. So I suggest that change the signature back in the core file to `escape($str)`

Comment: thanks @lbu, I changed it, the error code continues.

Comment: 'code' [19-Oct-2018 00:45:55 Etc/GMT-3] PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of ezSQL_mysql::query() should be compatible with ezSQLcore::query() in /home/u8242854/kartvizitstore.com/v4/ez_sql_mysql.php on line 0

Comment: It's the exact same thing. I think you will be better off using the latest version of ezSQL. you are using `2.03` while they are at `3.08`